# How can I check when a UITextView is being edited?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

I'm using the following code but it is not being recognised when I start editing the UITextView:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

[done setHidden:NO];

NSLog(@"Started editing target!");

}
```

Why is this?

I have added the delegate to the .h file too.

Comment: Are you sure you set the class containing this method as the delegate for the `UITextView`?

Comment: The method you have posted is part of the `UITextView` delegate protocol (`UITextViewProtocol`).  For it to work you'll need to set the delegate for the control to be the class you have posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the delegate of your UITextView. You need to connect the outlet to the delegate in Interface Builder or if you are creating it programmatically you can:

```
yourTextView.delegate = self;
```

to set the delegate to the controller you are inserting your element.

Answer (score 6):

```
if ([self.textView isFirstResponder]) ...
```

UPDATE: I include the full source to indicate UITextView definitely responds to isFirstResponder @d2burke

```
#import "TextViewController.h"

@interface TextViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@end

@implementation TextViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)click:(UIButton *)check
{
    BOOL isActive = [self.textView isFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"%d", isActive);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  UITextView doesn't respond to isFirstResponder

Comment: You're right, I read a thing, tested (failed) and misread another thing and commented hastily.  I've also updated my vote/down-vote.  Thanks for following back up and my apologies for being hasty.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you:

1. *nameOfTextView*.delegate = self;
2. show compiler you are using UITextViewDelegate in your class

Answer (score 1):

1. `Firstly you have to set UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>`
2. `Set`

   `yourTextview.delegate = self;`
3. `And catch this delegate using`

   `-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
   {
      [self.yourTextview setText:@""];
      [yourTextview setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Also could be a "duh" answer, but if you created your textView in IB, did you remember to connect the outlet up?